# Linux finding the mean of the memory usage of last hour

Tags: linux, memory, usage-statistics

i am trying to write a script that finds the mean of the *memory usage of last hour* and if it's above %60, mails to someone thats relevant.
I am trying this for days and i am completely lost. On the other hand i can't get any updates for my Ubuntu so i can't try someting like atop. I need this to work on other computers as well.
As far as i know ;

```
 free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
```

I am trying to use something like this in my code. Any help would appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

So i've built my scripts basics. But in this script i am getting the current ram usage.

```
#!/bin/sh

used=$(free -m | grep '^Mem' | awk '{print $3}')
total=$(free -m | grep '^Mem' | awk '{print $2}')
perct=$((($used*100)/$total))

echo "$perct%"

if [ $perct -gt 60 ] ; then

echo "Ram usage: $perct is above 60%" | mail -s "Critical Ram Usage" "example@example.com"

fi

#end
```

From this point , what can i do to improve my code ?

Comment: Lets say you have server1, from which you can ssh to the other computers.  Every 5 minutes, using `cron` your script could run the command and get 1 value per computer, and store it in 1 file per remote computer.  When you have 12 values, calculate the mean, check if it is >60%, send email, empty the file.  Make sure your command returns one number, nothing else, to it is easy to do the arithmetic later.

Comment: Rather than piping grep to awk and using multiple invocations to get `used` and `total`, you can write `read h total used _ <<< $(free | awk NR==2)`  If you don't want to use a herestring, you can do the same with a heredoc, but it's difficult to demonstrate in a comment.